# Get values from RETURNING * within a transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, sql-insert

When I have two `INSERT` SQL statements (see below) within a `begin;` and `commit;` transaction then the `RETURNING *` does not return anything but if I take out the `begin;` and `commit;` the `RETURNING *` does return the inserted record.
How can I get the `RETURNING *` to work within a transaction?

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO gis_field_configuration
   (level_unique_name, level_name_caption, use_for_charts, use_as_displayby, 
    displayby_label, data_type, level_help_text)
VALUES (
    '[john].[john]',
    'john',
    'false',
    'false',
    '',
    'text',
    'help text'
);

INSERT INTO gis_field_configuration_bycube
   (cube, level_unique_name)
VALUES (
    'Instruments',
    '[john].[john]'
) RETURNING *;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: How are you running the queries? If you send them in one batch, you won't get anything back, but you _should_ if you send them as usual, check the result of the actual query and COMMIT once you got the results...?

Comment: What do you actually need from your RETURNING statement?  The value of a serial id column?  if so, you could simplify, and just `select curval('the_relevant_sequence')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to use a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) and pack the two `INSERT`s into one command. Requires PostgreSQL **9.1** or later:

```
WITH x AS (
   INSERT INTO gis_field_configuration (level_unique_name, level_name_caption
                ,use_for_charts, use_as_displayby, displayby_label, data_type
                ,level_help_text)
   VALUES (
       '[john].[john]',
       'john',
       'false',
       'false',
       '',
       'text',
       'help text'
   )
   )
INSERT INTO gis_field_configuration_bycube
   (cube, level_unique_name)
VALUES (
    'Instruments',
    '[john].[john]'
    )
RETURNING *;
```

However, you **do** get values back with `RETURNING *` in any case. Just read them in *before* sending `COMMIT`. Sent in as batch, only results from the `last` command are returned - which would be the result of `COMMIT`, if you send *all* commands as one batch.

Hold back `COMMIT;` until you have received the results from the second `INSERT`.

---

#### In a plpgsql function

A function runs inside a transaction automatically . You don't need explicit BEGIN / COMMIT. To reuse values you get back from an `INSERT` use [`RETURNING *expressions* INTO [STRICT] *target*`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

Consider this simple demo:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (foo_id serial, bar text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_foo()
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   foo_var foo; -- type name = table name, fits return type of RETURNING *
   -- or use a generic type record
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO foo (bar)
   VALUES ('baz')
   RETURNING *
   INTO foo_var;

   RAISE NOTICE 'New id is: %', foo_var.foo_id;

   -- do stuff with foo_var

   END;
   $BODY$;

SELECT f_foo();
```

Comment: I ran the above WITH x AS ( statement and I got the following error:ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 2:    INSERT INTO gis_field_configuration (level_unique_name, l...
           ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 17

Comment: @JohnMitchell: which PostgreSQL version are you running? Updateable CTEs were introduced with 9.1

Comment: my postgres version is 8.4.9 so I guess that I can't utilize the WITH command.

Comment: @JohnMitchell: In this case, consider holding back `COMMIT;` until *after* you have received your return values.

Comment: How do I assign the results from the second insert to a temp variable so I can utilize after the COMMIT; statement?

Comment: @JohnMitchell: Are we talking about a plpgsql function? And are we talking about a single row (like in the example) or multiple rows? I added a basic example.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: So it appears that if you use a plpgsql function that you will not have to surround it within BEGIN /COMMIT statements but you do need the BEGIN /COMMIT statements surrounding the data-modifying CTE having  the two INSERTs in one command.  Am I correct in assuming that a CTE when having more than 1 insert will not behave as a transaction in that one insert could work and the other could fail but the one that worked would not be rolled back.

Comment: @JohnMitchell: No, you got that one wrong. A statement always succeeds as a whole or not at all. The query with the CTE is *one* statement. It can be part of a bigger transaction, but it's never split up by the database server.

Comment: Thanks they are going to upgrade our server from 8.4.9 to 9.1 maybe as early as today so I will then try replacing my transactions with a CME.

Comment: @JohnMitchell: CTE .. "Common Table Expression"

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're running all these statements as a single text string from your language's client driver. If that's the case, the result returned to the client will be what the *last statement* in the block of statements you sent returns. In this case that's the `COMMIT` statement, which has no result, so you get no result back.

Run each statement one-by-one and it should work fine. I can't give a more detailed example because you haven't mentioned which language you are using.

Here's a Python/psycopg example. The first approach where all the SQL is sent in one blob causes an exception when I try to get the results, because `commit` doesn't produce a result. The second example, where I run each statement separately and get the results of the `select` before  I `commit`, works fine.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
curs = conn.cursor();

# All in one blob
try:
    curs.execute("BEGIN; SELECT generate_series(1,10); COMMIT;")
    print(curs.fetchall())
except (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) as ex:
    print("Failed: ", ex)

# vs one-by-one
curs.execute("BEGIN;")
curs.execute("SELECT x.* FROM generate_series(1,10) x;")
print(curs.fetchall())
curs.execute("COMMIT;")
```

Output:

```
$ python3 test.py 
Failed:  no results to fetch
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (10,)]
```

Comment: You saved my day. I was getting problem calling from python code.